# Is there away to share/access the hdfs among developers?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Me new to bigdata and hive.
Need to work with other developer a spark streaming app, where it involves reading from Kafka and place it on hive/hdfs. The other developer uses/points to the same location of hdfs, reads the hive files and do the further processing.

My developement env is Eclipse on my windows system.
Other developer env is Eclipse on his machine.

As both are working on same files, is there anyway to share the hdfs path between us ?

Please share the details of how these kind of scenarios handled in spark development teams?

Advice best practices and etc.

Thanks a lot,
Shyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup multinode hadoop cluster and configured all developer System IP as  datanodes so that they can share same HDFS.

Main Conf file for Hadoop: **core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml,mapred-site.xml  & yarn-site.xml**

Once it done, you can install Hive and Spark over HDFS.

Please refer links for Setup: 
https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/how-to-install-and-set-up-hadoop-cluster/
https://dzone.com/articles/setting-up-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-just-got-easy-2

Comment: thank you Nikk , we have a hadoop cluster , but how to point it out from local ? i.e. how can I write into the path of hdfs location from my eclipse dev environment?

Comment: Local you mean Windows system where you are developing code?. If yes then  I think you will not b able to connect directly  from your IDE. You can write your code and run that jar over edges node of Hadoop clusters. You can use putty from windows systems to connect edge node and run that jar or write into Hdfs

Comment: yes unfortunately I am using windows as my development machine.  hdfs cluster is on linux.

Comment: if use Ubantu for local development , will i be able to access the hdfs folder i.e. which is on cluster ?

Comment: Yes for that you do not require Linux system just develop your code at window machine and move that jar to Linux system using WinSCP. connect your Putty to Linux system where Hadoop install and run that jar. It will be easy. If it is possible to connect hdfs from local which is not part of Hadoop clusters then that can create simpley security issue. Only possible solutions is use Putty for it. :)

Comment: Yes you can if you configure that Ubuntu system as a node in Hadoop clusters. To add node in cluster is very easy just check documents that I have share in link. You need to install Hadoop first in that Ubuntu and add that node in Hadoop configuration file. That's it.